# Special Characters in Angular Routing

Tags: angular, typescript, hyperlink, routes, character

Let's say I have a button that links to another page

```
   <button mat-button class="button" routerLink="{{ '/users/overview?'  + user?.Id }}">
         View User
   </button>
```

When you click the link it looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/users/overview%3F412

So it gets the correct user Id but has a problem with the speical character '?'... how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
  <button mat-button class="button" [routerLink]="'/users/overview'" [queryParams]="user?.Id">
     View User
```

Comment: I know, but this is cleaner approach.